# Как отправить сообщение в групповой чат telegram aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, сообщение

Как получить ID группового чата, и отправить сообщение именно туда используя aiogram?

Comment: Айди группы можно узнать добавив туда @Kuchizubot и прописав в чате "id"

Comment: Спасибо, а возможно ли узнать что сообщение пришло именно в лс боту а не в группу?

Comment: @LZLZZ, Есть специальные фильтры у aiogram'a -> https://telegra.ph/Vstroennye-filtry-v-aiogram-12-30 вас интересует ChatTypeFilter. https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Старайтесь не использовать чужих ботов, для уточнения нужного вам ID чата(группы).

Предположим, что бота который возвращает `ID` чата - не существует.

***Требования:***

1. У вас уже есть бот и токен.
2. У вас есть группа и ваш бот туда добавлен.

Осталось самое малое, написать простейший код для возвращения `ID` чата(группы).

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


API_TOKEN = 'API_TOKEN'


# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):    
    await message.reply(message.chat.id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]